# Cat refuses to stop meowing and scratching at doors in the middle of the night

Tags: cats, drinking, scratching

My 7 year old cat has started meowing very loudly all through the night and scratching at my bedroom door. He just started this behavior close to one week ago when i cleaned out a small water fountain that he drinks out of. Ive already tried recleanomg it to male sure nothing was left inside simce he is very picky with his water. He won't stop until someone gets up and does something for him which may include getting fresh water from the sink, attention or letting him in my room. He likes this but will go right back at it in 15 minutes.
Is there anything I should be looking out for or a way to train this behavior out of my cat so my family and I can sleep peacefully at night?